# Update query to update values incrementally and then loop PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write a query which will update the following below:

1. id = 1 --> id_scraping_account = 1
2. id = 2 --> id_scraping_account = 2
3. id = 3 --> id_scraping_account = 3
4. id = 4 --> id_scraping_account = 1
5. id = 5 --> id_scraping_account = 2
6. id = 6 --> id_scraping_account = 3

The main thing I am trying to understand is the structure of the query

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select id, id%3 as id_scraping_account
  from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

@PabloSantaCruz - almost. That however gives the resulting sequence 1,2,0. Should be:

```
select id, ((id-1)%3)+1 id_scraping_account 
  from your_table;
```